# I run the beautifulsoup code in python, and it runs in command in windows10 pro. In eclipse java, I get an error

Tags: java, python, beautifulsoup

I run the beautifulsoup code in python, and it runs in command in windows10 pro. In eclipse, I get an error.

```
I work in the following order
1. windows10 pro os   
2. python-3.7.3-amd64.exe ( install )
3. pip install bs4
4. pip install selenium
5. chrome webdrive download ( windows version )
6. coding
7. windows command line ( python web_test.py )
   execution ok 
8. but eclipse java project execute ....shows 
 ImportError: No module named bs4

result : command line excute success  but eclipse java project execute fail
```

---------------------------------------- python script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/python_source/util/chromedriver.exe')
```

--------------------- eclipse java proejct execute python script

```
System.setProperty("python.cachedir.skip", "true");
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.execfile("C:/3DP/webTest.py");
interpreter.exec("getData()");
```

Comment: Did you have eclipse make a virtualenv for your project?

Comment: I added virtualenv but it is added to the eclipse python project, but it is not added to eclipse java proejct